# How to use ansible when condition when string contains '@'

Tags: ansible

I am writing playbook to check user principal in kerberos servers. If principal exists it should skip task and if not it should create user principal. I am not sure how to use string with when condition I am trying below but getting errors

```
"ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'

    The error appears to be in '/home/revyas/RHELProjects/Atlas/eda-datalake/playbooks/provision-emr.yml': line 42, column 31, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:

          stat:
            path: "{{ user_dir }}"/"{{ keytab_name }}"
                                  ^ here
    We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
    missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
    start a value. For instance:

        with_items:
          - {{ foo }}

    Should be written as:

        with_items:
          - "{{ foo }}"
```

Playbook:

```
    - name: Check if user principals exist
      command: 'kadmin  -w "{{ emr_kdc_admin_password }}"  -p kadmin/admin listprincs'
      register: user_princs
      delegate_to : "{{ emr_kerberos_master }}"
      tags: "emr_acct"

    - name: Create user kerberos principal if not exist
      command: 'kadmin -w  {{ emr_kdc_admin_password }} -p kadmin/admin addprinc -randkey {{ kerberos_username }}@{{ emr_kerberos_realm }}'
      when: "{{ kerberos_username }}@{{ emr_kerberos_realm }}" not in user_princs.stdout

  delegate_to: "{{ emr_kerberos_master }}"
  tags: "emr_acct"



User principal from kdc have format given below:
emr-test1-aren-reetika@abd.xyz.com
emr-test-aren@bd.xyz.com 
emr-test-integration-test@bd.xyz.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first cited issue, yaml doesn't behave like python or shell which automatically concatenate string literals together

You'll want:

```yaml
     stat:
        path: "{{ user_dir }}/{{ keytab_name }}"
```

And the second error is because yaml believes the leading `"` is the start of a *YAML* literal, but in fact it's the start of a *Jinja2* literal, thus:

```yaml
  when: '"{{ kerberos_username }}@{{ emr_kerberos_realm }}" not in user_princs.stdout'
```

Or you can use any of the scalar folding syntaxes, if you prefer that:

```yaml
  when: >-
    "{{ kerberos_username }}@{{ emr_kerberos_realm }}" 
    not in user_princs.stdout
```

Comment: I tried these changes but ran into error "Tasks to Run: None [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: "{{ kerberos_username}}@{{emr_kerberos_realm}}" not in user_princs.stdout" localhost | FAILED | { - msg: The conditional check '"{{ kerberos_username}}@{{ emr_kerberos_realm}}" not in user_princs.stdout"' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected char u'"' at 80. String: {% if "emr-domino-reetikaintegration-test@EMR.EDA.COM" not in user_princs.stdout" %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}

Comment: Sure, you have an extra `"` after the word `stdout`; pick one style or the other -- either wrap the expression in double, and the string literal in single, or -- as I did -- wrap the string literal in double and the whole thing in single

Answer (score 1):

```
when: "{{ kerberos_username }}@{{ emr_kerberos_realm }}" not in user_princs.stdout
```

change to

```
when: "{{ kerberos_username }}\\@{{ emr_kerberos_realm }}" not in user_princs.stdout
```